How can I make sure my exe file recognise my dll file which is in a folder called binary adjacent to my exe file
The log output generated by the compiler
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\user\source\repos\FirstPersonShooter\x64\Debug\FpsKing.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Visual studio\cpp\lib\SFML\bin\sfml-graphics-d-2.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Visual studio\cpp\lib\SFML\bin\sfml-window-d-2.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Visual studio\cpp\lib\SFML\bin\sfml-system-d-2.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140_1d.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin\libstdc++-6.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\opengl32.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. 
'FpsKing.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. 

The folder structure of the prgram listed
|
|-[my exe file]
|-binary
    └──[all my dll files]

I am encountering an Entry Point Not Found error when trying to run my application (FpsKing.exe). The error occurs before any code in my application executes, as verified by breakpoints placed at the beginning of the program.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD1BE9F90D (ntdll.dll) in FpsKing.exe: 0xC0000139: Entry Point Not Found.
The thread 34924 has exited with code 3221225785 (0xc0000139).
The thread 30020 has exited with

 code 3221225785 (0xc0000139).
The program '[27764] FpsKing.exe' has exited with code 3221225785 (0xc0000139) 'Entry Point Not Found'.

I am attempting to load my DLLs dynamically and have specified their locations in a manifest file. The manifest file should guide the application to locate the DLLs as if they were in the same directory as the executable.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity
        version="1.0.0.0"
        processorArchitecture="*"
        name="FpsKing"
        type="win32"
    />
    <file name="binary\openal32.dll"/>
    <file name="binary\sfml-graphics-d-2.dll"/>
    <file name="binary\sfml-audio-d-2.dll"/>
    <file name="binary\sfml-network-d-2.dll"/>
    <file name="binary\sfml-system-d-2.dll"/>
    <file name="binary\sfml-window-d-2.dll"/>
</assembly>


When the dll files are placed next to the exe, the application loads perfectly
However, placing the DLLs in the binary subdirectory results in Entry Point not Found error

It has been suggest that system environment would be required, but I personally am speculating whether I can use a manifest file which would point to the dll files in the binary folder without the need to configure the system variables
Suppose the manifest file would guide my exe to search for the dll?
Or am I a massive dummy that linked statically in visual studio config and dynamically linked in my code?
EDIT: Dependency walker shows error when dll files are present adjacent to the exe leading to the exe running but I do not want dll being adjacent. Though the dll files have a red icon which isnt present when my exe functions
Here is a photo when the executable does not functions due to entry point not found:

Is there any update? Have you tried the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/78747428/16764520

Courtesy to https://medium.com/@onerecovery/full-guide-how-to-fix-entry-point-not-found-error-2023-cae1e205dfea
The problem

The entry point is a doorpoint to software or programs that hands-off control of the process from OS to the app on some resources. The Entry Point Not Found error message usually occurs when you fail to open a program with an error message of program name.exe — Entry Point Not Found. The system fails to locate the function or the procedure in a required DLL (Dynamic Link Library) file, which indicates there is a necessary file in a certain process missing or corrupted, leading to the program’s failure to launch. For example, When you open Photoshop, iTunes, Chrome, or else, the system can not find the key to open the door of your app; the key (file necessary to hand off that process) is missing, damaged, or corrupted.


Possible causes:

virus issues
software installation problems
system file issues
registry issues
disk drive errors
driver problems

How to fix this issue?
First and foremost you will need to find out whether the DLL is infected or corrupted, so on a secure machine check it for viruses and if it's not infected, test this DLL there. If it works, then something's off with your system. If it does not work, then you have some other problem (and you may also have a problem with the system).
To fix your system, open cmd and run
sfc /scannow

Look carefully at the results of scannow, whether it found problems. Reboot your machine and test your dll again.
If the problem still persists, try uninstalling and reinstalling your dependencies.
If the problem still persists, download the DLL from a trusted source and try it instead of the copy that you have, make sure that the version is correct.
Make sure your drivers are up to date, or that they are compatible with the version of your DLL.
Of course, you will need to eradicate any viruses and have a fresh virus database, this goes without saying.
If the DLL was working earlier, then you might consider restoring your computer to a previous point.

I edited my info see if its more helpful for you, thanks man im new to all of thsi dll hell

@Log-e happy to help! In your screenshot, we can see errors related to 1. not found forward dependency, 2. unresolved import due to missing exports, 3. circular dependency. In the right-hand side there are further errors that are not shown completely in the screenshot, but they seem to claim some files are missing. So it seems that there is a missing dependency and it would make sense to try and find that dependency and install it and then try again. I know it's repetitive and you are worried, but it should be resolvable in a finite amount of steps.

it seems that my manifest file despite compiled into the executable seems to be failing its job to help my exe locate my dll files, when I remove the dll and put it into the bin folder it has entry point not found but when I put my dll files next to the exe it works like a charm despite having errors in the dependency walker so these error doesnt matter in my context, I've tried your method and restarted my pc with the scan function though it still doesn't work, do you know how to make my manifest file and my exe locate my dll files better? maybe some visual studio config?

@Log-e You could load your library explicitly via LoadLibrary("subFolder\\openal32.dll"); instead of setting it in the manifest. If that helps.

I have loadlibrary but it immediately says entry point error without even loading the program, like it doesnt run anything so my loadlibrary doesnt even load

like I really want to make loadlibrary works but I need my program to be like oh there is loadlibrary so dont panick yet and give me entry point error. I have load library and everything already Ill add some new things in the above to show you my code but rn I need to make sure  it doesnt get entry point error first

To use loadlibrary,  remove the input -> xxx.lib setting in the project properties.
